# Attach multiple times to a single screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

I've been using `screen -dRaA -S x` to open up a single session between different workstations as I move about. Handy.

Is it possible to connect multiple times to a single session, though, without disconnecting others? When I have two machines I'm quickly moving between even reconnecting starts to slow me down.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

```
screen -aAxR -S x
```

`-x` is the option that does what you want.

Answer (score 29):

`screen -x` is the option you want (coupled with whichever other options you desire).

The `-x` replaces `-R` in this case.

Answer (score 13):

I'm personally a fan of:

```
$ screen -rxU
```

-r resumes a detached screen session
-x resumes a not-detached screen session
-U tells the terminal to use UTF-8 encoding (which I use exclusively)

Answer (score 6):

`screen -x SCREEN_NAME`

From GNU Screen `man` page:

> -x   Attach to a not detached screen session. (Multi display mode).

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled upon this now, 4 years later.

There is an alternative perfect for what this question requires:

`tmux`
to start a new session, and to attach to it use `tmux attach`

If there are more than one session, use `tmux attach -t SESSION_NAME` which is available through `tmux ls` or bottom of the screen.

Comment: Why the downvote?