# How to Attach Screen Sessions that were Split

Tags: gnu-screen, gnome-terminal

I am working with `screen` and I am having a hard time with reattaching sessions where I split the screen within one session. Is this even possible?

I have tried searching for it on here and google but there doesn't seem to be any posting on this type of use-case.
here are some resources I was using:

- http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference
- https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/
- [Attach multiple times to a single screen session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35180/attach-multiple-times-to-a-single-screen-session)
- https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahrm

My scenario is this, when I create multiple splits within a single session, for example I run the following commands to create a session and split the screens:

```
screen -S multiplesplitexample
```

`ctrl+a`  `|`

`ctrl+a` `tab`

`ctrl+a` `c`

Once I get the environment setup the way I want I then detach it by running:

`ctrl+a` `d`

now I can see my session when I run `screen -ls`:

```
root@kali:~# screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    6398.multiplesplitexample (02/09/2019 11:46:17 AM) (Detached)
1 Socket in /run/screen/S-root.
```

No matter what I run i.e. `screen -r multiplesplitexample`, `screen -dRR`, etc. it reattaches the screen session with only one of the screen terminals that was originally two split screen terminals within one screen.

I am able to see the two screen terminals by running

`ctrl + a` `"`

```
Num Name    Flags
  0 bash    $
  1 bash    $
```